# Uppercase example. Computation Error: Output file for the task is absent

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, grid-computing, boinc

I am using the [uppercase example](https://github.com/BOINC/boinc/tree/master/samples/example_app) from the BOINC samples in order to build BOINC app for android. I have setup my server using this [tutorial](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/CloudServer), and I am following this [tutorial](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/AndroidBuildApp) to build the BOINC app for android.

**What have I done so far?**

- Built the androidarm toolchain
- Built openssl and curl arm libraries
- Built boinc arm libraries
- Compiled the uppercase source code without any errors.

All these steps were done using the ARM scripts given [here](https://github.com/BOINC/boinc/tree/master/android). I have uploaded the compiled uppercase app in the `apps -> example_app->30000->arm-android-linux-gnu`folder

**Issues I have encountered**

Downloaded the BOINC from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.berkeley.boinc&hl=en), and added my own project URL. It downloaded all the tasks. The tasks were running but it stopped because of the missing output as shown in the screenshots. I have searched about the issue, and someone said in other forums that

> 'Output file absent' is always a symptom of an earlier failure, not a
>   problem in itself

I am trying to understand what went wrong having followed all the steps.

Tested on Android 5.0, 4.2, 4.1 on ARM architecture but the results are the same. I made the windows client version, and it is working fine.

[image: Event Log]
 [image: Tasks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem some time ago, the solution was to add a file extension to the input file. For example input.txt instead of just a file named input